# Typescript - Exported variable (dictionary) is undefined after importing

Tags: angular, typescript

On a .ts file I define a dictionary as following:

```
export var substatuses = {
    'not_actuated': {
        name: 'Not actuated',
        color: '#F52323',
        iconColor: 'color-red'
    },
    'executing_procedure': {
        name: 'Executing procedure',
        color: '#F78521',
        iconColor: 'color-orange'
    },
    'procedure_executed': {
        name: 'Procedure executed',
        color: '#F2C618',
        iconColor: 'color-yellow'
    },
    'unknown': {
        name: 'Unknown',
        color: '#767676',
        iconColor: 'color-gray'
    },
    'can_not_act': {
        name: 'Can not act',
        color: '#0082F0',
        iconColor: 'color-blue'
    },
    'ok': {
        name: 'Ok',
        color: '#36B07F',
        iconColor: 'color-green'
    },
};
```

Then on an Angular component, I import it by:

```
import { substatuses } from 'src/app/core/dictionaries/substatuses';
```

And try to use as a normal dictionary:

```
substatuses['ok']
```

But I get an "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined".

Why isn't my variable being initialized before my component?

Comment: that `var` is first candidate to change to `const` also question would be better if you actualy asked for why `substatuses['ok']` does trigger error as all that additional `this.geoMarkers.features[i].properties.elements[ii].scenarios[iii].substatus` is just obfuscating and actualy you should test if that actualy is the error source

Comment: sute it is aaaaaand, it solves the problem. Don't know why.

Comment: hmm that error is somwhere in that `this.geoMarkers.features[i].properties.elements[ii].scenarios[iii].substatus` you need to debug it further

Comment: Using strings to access objects in an ugly way doesn't make them into C# style dictionaries.  just saying...

Comment: @AluanHaddad my point was to differentiate them from the object ones.

Comment: @DenisCandido and that is precisely my point. They _are_ objects and pretending otherwise is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared using `var` are hoisted (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), which means when they are defined and when the value is set may not match what's in your code.

The best approach nowadays is to just not use `var` at all. Declare all your variables using ES6 `const` or `let`, and they will no longer be hoisted and so easier to understand.